# Paypal Trial Payment

Tags: paypal, express-checkout, paypal-nvp

I'm trying to setup a trial payment option using the NVP API. I want to offer the customer "pay nothing for 30 days" option.

I've got this working but my client has pointed out that on the checkout page the total shows up as if to suggest the customer will actually be paying now.

Is there any way to set up a trial payment and have zero show up on the Paypal checkout page?

Comment: Shouldn't this be a question for paypal to answer?

Answer (score 0):

I got to the bottom of this problem by only setting these properties in the initial call `SetExpressCheckout`:

```
$args['RETURNURL']          = $returnURL;
$args['CANCELURL']          = $cancelURL;
$args['NOSHIPPING']             = 1;
$args['ALLOWNOTE']          = 0;
$args['LOCALECODE']             = 'GB';

$args['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL']     = $notifyURL;
$args['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM']    = $invoice;
$args['L_BILLINGTYPE0']         = 'RecurringPayments';
$args['L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0'] = $description;
```

This just displays the description of your product on the Paypal checkout page. `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` sets up the trial plan, include these properties:

```
$args['TRIALBILLINGPERIOD']     = 'Day';
$args['TRIALBILLINGFREQUENCY']      = 30;
$args['TRIALTOTALBILLINGCYCLES']    = 1;
$args['TRIALAMT']                   = $amount;
```